# Programmatically Set Spacing on Stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Like the title says, I have searched around but had no luck. Is it possible to connect the stack view to the .swift file and then adjust the spacing programmatically? Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.spacing = 10.0      // or whatever you like
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a custom **UIStackView**

```
class YourCustomSublcass {
  //MARK: Initialization of the stackView
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.spacing = 8.0
  }

  required init(coder :NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.spacing = 8.0
  }
}
```